# php multidimensional array - value minus 1

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-splice

I am having trouble with my multidimensional array.

I have various items in the array.

The name and quantity of each item are displayed on the screen, with a - and + button to alter the quantity of each item by 1. Each button is a form posting back to the same page.

The example below is the function that is called when i click on the - button. It is supposed to subtract one from the quantity of the item.

It is correctly deducting one from the quantity and the item_id is correct. However, it is not updating the correct array item. In fact it seems to be creating a new array item, as a new item is appearing under the other items in the basket when the minus button is pressed.

I don't think I am referencing the correct array item in the array_splice call. I don't think I should be saying "$thisKey," after "array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"]".

But, I'm not sure how to reference the array item I want correctly.

Please advise.

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['itemMinus']) && $_POST['itemMinus'] != "") {
// Access the array and run code to remove that array index
$thisKey = $_POST['itemMinus'];
$thisKeyQuantity = $_POST['itemMinusQuantity'];
if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
} else {
    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $thisKey, 1, 
 array(array("item_id" => $thisKey, "quantity" => $thisKeyQuantity - 1)));
     }
 }
```

/****************/

Solution:

Big thanks to Jeroen Bollen for contribution to solution.
My code now works as so:

```
if (isset($_POST['itemMinus']) && $_POST['itemMinus'] != "") {
// Access the array and run code to remove that array index
$thisKey = $_POST['itemMinus'];
$thisKeyQuantity = $_POST['itemMinusQuantity'];
if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
} else {
    $i=0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $key => $value) {
        if($value['item_id'] == $thisKey) {
            array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i, 1, array(array("item_id" => $thisKey, "quantity" => $thisKeyQuantity - 1)));
            break;
             }
              else{$i++;}//end if
         }//end foreach
     }//end else
 }//end if POST
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is your actual question? We can't do much with `please advise`.

Comment: @Joren Apologies Joren. I've updated the post and tried to make it a bit clearer. I think the problem is I'm not correctly referencing the item i want to in the array_splice call. Is it possible to undo my minus ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value['item_id'] == $thisKey) {
        $value['quantity']--;
        break; // Stop the loop, we're done
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. That seems to have done the trick. I put an index on your foreach loop and used that to reference the correct array pair. Excellent thanks. I'll put the finished code in the original post for reference.